# Does a morale bonus affect the modifier?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

When I my Barbarian flies into a rage he gains amongst other things +4 morale bonus to Strength. Does this affect the modifier too?

My strength is 18STR+MOD4

If I add the morale bonus is it 22STR+MOD4 or 22STR+MOD6?

Comment: Part of the issue here may come from the game's vocabulary: a [bonus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/glossary#TOC-Bonus) is different from an [ability score modifier](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores), for instance.

Comment: I feel like you're mixing scores and modifiers; your Strength wouldn't be 18+Mod4, it should be interpreted as 18 (4), where 18 is the score and 4 is how much it affects related rolls (the mod is always == SCORE-10 // 2, no matter what. There is no such thing as 22Str with a mod of 4). Any modifier is based on the score and derived from the score, there is no concept of changing the modifier directly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [barbarian](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian)'s [rage](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian#TOC-Rage-Ex-) grants the barbarian bonuses to the barbarian's ability *scores*, not directly to the barbarian's ability score *modifiers*.

For example, a barbarian that normally possesses a Strength of 18 enters a rage, gaining a +4 morale bonus to his Strength *score*. Normally, such a barbarian's Strength *modifier* is +4 (for having Str 18) but while in that rage the barbarian's Strength *modifier* is +6 (for having Str 22).

***Note:*** Don't feel hemmed in by the ability score bonuses from rage being merely Temporary [Ability Score Bonuses](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/ability-scores#TOC-Ability-Score-Bonuses). [This FAQ entry](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9rbg) (from a [2013 messageboard post](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2q60x&page=5?4-temporary-increases-to-Strength-How-does-it#243) by Pathfinder Design Team) clarifies that items listed as changed by temporary ability score bonuses are to ease bookkeeping rather than a finite list of changes.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48893/discussion-on-answer-by-hey-i-can-chan-does-a-morale-bonus-affect-the-modifier).